# MySQL - Select Records that matches all values

Tags: mysql, join, select

If a table "XYZ" contains two columns as combine primary key, I need to select records that contain both Value1 `and` Value2 in COLUMN_B ( Result: ID4 )

I tried with "IN" query but it returns the records which contain VALUE1 `OR` VALUE2 in COLUMN_B (ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4).

Can anybody please help me to write a MySQL query that can do this.

```
COLUMN_A    COLUMN_B

ID1         Value1
ID2         Value1
ID3         Value2
ID4         Value1
ID4         Value2
ID5         Value3
ID3         Value3
```